# Drupal7: I need to inject category name in my node using mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars)

Tags: drupal-7

Hello I need to display the category name of the article (it is in taxonomy) inside my node. Here is the function

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
        $node = $vars['node'];
        $vars['category'] = "category here..";
    }
```

With my devel_themer module I manage to find out where this category is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That output doesn't look right, in Drupal 7 there is an extra array key wrapped around fields for the language. Try this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node']; 

  $term = taxonomy_term_load($node->field_category[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid']);
  $vars['category'] = check_plain($term->name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clive, I think is an elegant way ..I'll try it and come up with a feedback

Comment: It actually works. The only big problem it is only available within node-- tempaltes. I don't know how to deal with view-- templates. There it won't work.